# I can't call my class in to main function

Tags: c++, function, class, object, program-entry-point

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;

class student 
   {

        private:
            char name [30], location[50], ic[20];
            int age;

        public:
            void set_data()
            {
                cout<<"Enter name       :";
                cin.getline(name, 30);
                cout<<"Enter location       :";
                cin.getline(location, 50);
                cout<<"Enter IC     :";
                cin.getline(ic, 20);
                cout<<"Enter age        :";
                cin>>age;
            }

            void display()
           {
               cout<<"Name       :"<<name<<endl;
               cout<<"IC         :"<<ic<<endl;
               cout<<"Location   :"<<location<<endl;
               cout<<"Age        :"<<age<<endl;
           }
    }student s1;

   int main()
{   

    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"WELCOME TO A-PLUS TUITION CENTER"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

    student set_data();


    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"STUDENT INFORMATION"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

    student display();

return 0;
}
```

guys please help me... I'm stucked here.. i need the output to be like this but i have problems of calling the class into main function.. what should I do?

```
--------------------------------
WELCOME TO A-PLUS TUITION CENTER
--------------------------------
Enter Name     : Usha Vellappan
Enter Location : Melaka
Enter IC       : 750217016680
Enter age      : 30

--------------------------------
STUDENT INFOMATION
--------------------------------
Name      : Usha Vellappan
IC        : 750217016680
Location  : Melaka
Age       : 30


Press any key to continue
```

Comment: What is the problem? It seems to be working.

Comment: First read on OOP concepts. It is simply all about creating instances of classes and calling methods through those instances. Give it a try by yourself first

Comment: I strongly suggest you get a C++ book and start reading it.

Comment: my error now is its "expected initializer before 's1'... so how do i change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering for just this example, you are doing something very wrong...

i fixed the code

```
#include<iostream>
```

using namespace std;

class student 
   {

```
    private:
        char name [30], location[50], ic[20];
        int age;

    public:
        void set_data()
        {
            cout<<"Enter name       :";
            cin.getline(name, 30);
            cout<<"Enter location       :";
            cin.getline(location, 50);
            cout<<"Enter IC     :";
            cin.getline(ic, 20);
            cout<<"Enter age        :";
            cin>>age;
        }

        void display()
       {
           cout<<"Name       :"<<name<<endl;
           cout<<"IC         :"<<ic<<endl;
           cout<<"Location   :"<<location<<endl;
           cout<<"Age        :"<<age<<endl;
       }
}s1;
```

int main()
{

```
cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"WELCOME TO A-PLUS TUITION CENTER"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

s1.set_data();


cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"STUDENT INFORMATION"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

s1.display();
```

return 0;
}

but still i'll recommend you reading some book for c++..

Comment: it does work :D thanks alot.. well i just started c++ less than a month and i got this work from my lecturer.. and sure i'll read more about c++

Comment: thats cool,..:D
learn..
as much as u can..
its a tremendous language...
All The Very Best...

Comment: lets say if i have to insert looping structure in main function.. where should i insert it? example as for loop

Comment: after the 1st set of cout statements..
just before s1.set_data();

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Its working as expected.

```
#include<iostream>  

using namespace std;

class student {

        private:
            char name [30], location[50], ic[20];
            int age;

        public:
            void set_data()
            {
                cout << "Enter name       : ";
                cin.getline(name, 30);
                cout<<  "Enter location   : ";
                cin.getline(location, 50);
                cout<<  "Enter IC         : ";
                cin.getline(ic, 20);
                cout<<  "Enter age        : ";
                cin>>age;

            }

            void display()
           {
               cout<<"Name       : "<<name<<endl;
               cout<<"IC         : "<<ic<<endl;
               cout<<"Location   : "<<location<<endl;
               cout<<"Age        : "<<age<<endl;
           }
};

int main()
{   

    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"WELCOME TO A-PLUS TUITION CENTER"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

    student s;
    s.set_data();


    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"STUDENT INFORMATION"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;

    s.display();

    return 0;
}
```